# PhpStorm custom time to index files

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a very, very large project in PhpStorm that is about 10 GB in size.

Unfortunately, every time I open this software, it starts scanning files.

Is it possible to set it to index at any time?
I did not find a section in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set it to index at any time?

That is not possible.

- The indexing is done on a start as the IDE works with your indexed/parsed code in order to offer code completion, find usages, refactoring and other stuff.
- The indexing is slow on the first run as the IDE needs to actually scan and parse all the files. Subsequent project openings are much faster: the IDE scans the project files looking for changes and only re-indexes new/modified files.
- If you open a project in a new IDE version or after invalidating the caches, the IDE  will re-index the whole thing again.

---

You can mark certain folders (that do not participate in code completion like logs, DB dumps, product images, user generated content, generated code files etc) as **Excluded** so they are not getting indexed (they still will be scanned/checked for changes but not parsed/indexed).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/indexing.html